# JOIN on primary key (INT), WHERE by alphanumeric UID (VARCHAR)... Is it optimal?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, uid

The goal is to change this URL...

```
app.com/journals/3/items
```

into

```
app.com/journals/aWNtFJXeYuvyhyJpqAjW/items
```

...and I was wondering if this is the optimal way to do it i.e. **join on id, search by uid**.

```sql
SELECT 
   ji.*,
   j.uid journalUid
FROM journalItems ji
   LEFT JOIN journal j ON j.id = ji.journalId
WHERE
   j.uid = 'aWNtFJXeYuvyhyJpqAjW'
```

```
journal
+----+----------------------+--------+
| id |    uid VARCHAR(20)   |  name  |
+----+----------------------+--------+
|  1 | cerGJ8cMKMK2njBtgsMy |   foo  |
|  2 | aWNtFJXeYuvyhyJpqAjW |   bar  |     <------- journal
|  3 | 7zwACt4fHkEchSjeeW7j |   baz  |      
+----+----------------------+--------+            

journalItems                                        
+----+----------------------+--------+-----------+ 
| id |    uid VARCHAR(20)   |  name  | journalId |
+----+----------------------+--------+-----------+ 
|  1 | ncv3VTlOMls6RPejJsjq |    a   |     1     | 
|  2 | NPz9CKEk7w14fKqIkCI2 |    b   |     1     |
|  3 | jghhnU29IKoOoG4smM4W |    c   |     1     |
|  4 | YE1nFNzjnusuyZeMNFWF |    d   |     2     |      <------- item
|  5 | 5N15UTgDgRjRKwt3yUCC |    e   |     2     |      <------- item
|  6 | 0eTBq3Ptzjbw32LkAQ0j |    f   |     3     |
+----+----------------------+--------+-----------+
```

Here's the UID generator:

```js
function generateUid() {
    let length = 20;
    let uid = "";
    let characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        uid += characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    }
    return uid;
}
```

Comment: If you really want LEFT JOIN result, you should move the j.uid condition from WHERE to ON. As it is now, you get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. What do you think about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is undoing the `left join`, so you might as well use a regular `join`:

```
SELECT ji.*, j.uid as journalUid
FROM journalItems ji JOIN
     journal j
     ON j.id = ji.journalId
WHERE j.uid = 'aWNtFJXeYuvyhyJpqAjW';
```

For performance, you want indexes on `journalItems(journalId)` and on `journal(uid, id)`.

Otherwise, your query is fine, although it seems odd that you want putting `j.uid` in the result set when you are only selecting one of them.